# How can I disable the autostart of Brasero when I insert a blank CD/DVD?

Tags: cd, dvd

When a blank media inserted, the burning tool automatically started. Is there a way to disable that feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Nautilus** under **Edit > Preferences > Media**:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be valid anymore for Ubuntu 11

Answer (score 1):

System > Preferences > Preferred Applications

On the **media** tab, below **Other Media**, select **blank CD disk** and change action to **Do Nothing** or **Ask what do do** as you prefer. Do the same for the other blank media types.

Comment: I knew that, but on my 10.04 in Preferred applications there is no such a tab... Hey anyway thank you for the reply.

Comment: In 12.04 it is no longer accessed from Nautilus! It has moved to Unity Dash -> System Preferences -> System -> Details -> Removable Media